Modify slurm job's launch host
We are developing a custom select plugin lib for Slurm which will give
custom allocations to a Slurm job.
We can't find a way to modify the launch host for a job. The node list order that is fed as part of host bitmap from the select plugin is taken verbatim & the 1st host is used as the launch host.
Wish to know if there's a way in Slurm by which we can modify the slurm 1st host.
The call to Select Plugin (from slurmctld) is the form:
select_p_job_test(job_recort_t job_ptr,
bitstr_t node_bitmap*,
uint32_t min_nodes, ...)*
Here node_bitmap, supposedly, has the node list from the allocation from select plugin & the 1st host is used as the launch host.
Example Usage:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Assume there are 4 hosts in a slurm cluster each with 4 cores.
Let's call the hosts: slurm-h1, slurm-h2, slurm-h3 & slurm-h4.
Suppose, a job requiring 9 cores (say sbatch -n 9 xterm) is placed on hosts: slurm-h2 (4 cores), slurm-h3 (4 cores), slurm-h4 (4 cores) when placement is given from the select API select_p_job_test(). This allocation is entered through the node_bitmap.
It's found that slurm-h2 always turns out to be launch host & we can't make it slurm-h3 or slurm-h4.
We can't tweak the node bitmap here.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Q: Is there a way to tweak the received node_bitmap to make a particular one as the launch host? Alternatively, does slurmctld (in Slurm) has any other hook / call back function to help developer in changing the launch host once the node allocation is seen by slurmctld?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Tried to change the launch host (1st host in slurm node-list).
But unable to do so & the node list is taken in alphabetical order.
